# Could the metric be a tensor product of a 4-vector with itself?

Tags: electromagnetism, spacetime, metric-tensor, potential, curvature

I am really keen on the idea of geometrizing all of physics using the spacetime manifold, so I was happy to find this paper:

https://doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/1956/1/012017

As I understand it, they demonstrate that Maxwell's equations are a *consequence* of the vacuum Einstein equation, IF you suppose that the following relation between the metric and the electromagnetic 4-potential:

$g_{\mu\nu} = A_{\mu}A_{\nu}$

They further identify 4-current with $\nabla_{\mu}\nabla^{\nu}A_{\nu}$ and explain how this relates to Weyl curvature.

Now I am eager to subscribe to a theory like this, but I'm not convinced that it is valid to build the metric from a self-tensor-product like that.  My reasoning is this: take a local orthonormal coordinate frame in which the $A$ 4-vector lies along the $x^0$ direction.  Then $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ are all zero, so when you take the tensor product, the resulting metric will only have one non-zero component, ie. it will be degenerate.  Maybe if it were only one point that would be fine, but as I see it this will happen at every point in the spacetime.

Am I missing something?  In general the authors seem to be well versed in tensor calculus and so forth, and it is certainly an alluring hypothesis.

Comment: You are right. The outer product of two vectors is a matrix of rank 1 so it cannot be inverted. Note that https://www.aalto.fi/en/news/a-new-interpretation-of-quantum-mechanics-suggests-that-reality-does-not-depend-on-the-person describes these authors as hobby physicists.

Comment: $A_{\mu}$ satisfies the Maxwell eqn and there is a gauge dependence due to $A^2=4$. So this is not the usual classical electrodynamics on a curved manifold. Classical observables should be gauge independent which is not the case here, so this may not be a physical theory

Comment: I took a look at the paper. They don't derive anything, they just say $g_{\mu\nu}=A_\mu A_\nu$ and then after a lot of words write down the Maxwell action. The Maxwell action can't possibly follow from the Einstein Hilbert action with $g_{\mu\nu}=A_\mu A_\nu$ since you need to use the inverse metric to define the Ricci scalar, and $\det g=0$ everywhere in spacetime for this "metric."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP is correct, this object, $A_μA_ν$, could not be *the pseudo-Riemmanian  metric* of the usual formulation of electromagnetism in special or general relativity. However, I would not be so quick to completely dismiss the theory without studying it in more details.

First, within the more established way of geometrization of electomagnetism, [Kaluza–Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory), the object $A_μA_ν$ does crop up as a *part* of the metric. Specifically: the 5-dimensional metric when restricted to 4-dimensions is not the inverse of “inverse 5-dimensional metric” restricted in turn to 4-dimensions, and the difference is proportional to $A_μA_ν$.

Second, geometrization of Newtonian gravitation, [Newton–Cartan theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory) uses rank 1 *temporal metric*, $t_{μν}$ to measure time/temporal lengths. This object could be thought of as a tensor product of covector with itself $t_{μν}=τ_μ τ_ν$. The *second* metric of the Newton–Cartan theory is rank-3 spatial metric to measure distances/spatial lengths.

So, *without reading the paper* I would not be surprised that one can indeed use $A_μA_ν$ as some sort of *a metric* in some geometric formulation of electromagnetism.

> I am really keen on the idea of geometrizing all of physics using the spacetime manifold …

As an advise, I would recommend to familiarize yourself with more traditional routes of geometrizing physics (such as mentioned above Kaluza–Klein and Newton–Cartan theories) before studying more radical/lesser known ideas.

Comment: There's good insights here, but I looked at the paper and it does indeed claim $g_{\mu\nu}=A_\mu A_\nu$ (it's not a Kaluza Klein decomposition). I guess I also just want to quibble that I don't think $\tau_{\mu\nu}=t_\mu t_\nu$ is a great example, because in that case the time metric $\tau_{\mu\nu}$ is describing a 1 dimensional space, so there is no problem representing it as a rank-1 tensor. Having said all of that, this answer is quite insightful, and I very much agree with the suggestion that the OP focus on more standard methods. +1.

Comment: @Andrew, Re your quibble: In NC geometry without additional constraints time metric no longer necessarily describes absolute time, it is a tensor on whole *space-time* manifold. For instance, there could be torsional NC (TNC) geometry with different flow of time at different points. See e.g. works of Hartong, Obers and others. So actually, it is a great example for geometrization, hopefully made even better by our discussion.

Comment: The way I would describe it is that you are embedding an infinite number of one-dimensional manifolds (the worldlines corresponding to your chosen time coordinate as a function of space) into a higher dimensional space. From the point of view of the full spacetime, you then have a projection operator $P^\mu_a$ which takes you from the full spacetime (with a $\mu$ index) to the submanfiold (with an $a$ index). The induced metric on the submanifold is then $g_{ab} = P^\mu_a P^\nu_a g_{\mu\nu}$ (where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric in the full spacetime).

Comment: (...) Since the submanifold in this case is 1d, there's no need for an $a$ index, so you can identify $t^\mu$ as the projection operator. Anyway, the aspect I'm quibbling about is that there actually only is one non-zero eigenvalue needed to measure intervals in a one dimensional manifold, whereas the main problem with the paper is that in four spacetime dimensions, it is a show stopper to have a metric with only one nonzero eigenvalue everywhere in space. Having said that, I think NC is a nice example to know about in general, and shows in what situation a rank-1 tensor can be a metric.

Answer (score 3):

No, here's why. The outer product of a vector with itself is a projection operator with a scaling of the vector's Euclidian length squared, and it projects down to the space parallel to the vector. It is not, therefore, invertible. The metric tensor must be invertible, so a single outer product of a vector with itself cannot be the metric tensor.

You could produce a metric tensor by summing the outer product of 4 linearly independent 4-vector fields with themselves, but that is basically the [vielbein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism) formalism.